# How to list all IAM principals and roles from Google Cloud IAM across multi projects / folders?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-iam

We can list all iam service accounts as follows:

```
gcloud iam service-accounts list
```

We can list all iam roles as follows:

```
gcloud iam roles list
```

This works fine for one project only.

I have however multiple projects and they are organized by **folders**. I would like to list therefore all IAM principles and roles in one go. How can this be achieved?

Comment: Stack overflow encourages questions that include an attempt solve the solution for yourself. Questions asking folks to write solutions for you are discouraged and likely to get downvoted|closed.

Comment: I am perfectly aware of the requirements of a question, and I have demonstrated how to do it for a single project. There is no point on trying something just like that in this scenario. That is just nit picking. There is also clear value of my question, as larger organizations often manage multi projects and thus having an overview at organization level is relevant. Also as a feedback to Google engineers reading this question.

Comment: What do you want  to look at? What's the real questions? Listing the service accounts and the roles has no sense if you have a large organisation. If you want to know all the permissions of a specific service account, now you have a real value to know/understand the scope of an account. So, what's your real world question?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List all Project IDs:

```bash
gcloud projects list --format="value(projectId)"
```

List all Service Account (Emails) by Project (IDs):

```bash
PROJECTS=$(\
  gcloud projects list \
  --format="value(projectId)")

for PROJECT in ${PROJECTS}
do
  echo "Project: ${PROJECT}"
  gcloud iam service-accounts list \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --format="value(email)"
done
```

IIUC `gcloud iam roles list` is a global list

For the custom role (names) in a Project, you want:

```bash
gcloud iam roles list \
--project=${PROJECT} \
--format="value(name)"
```

So perhaps:

```bash
PROJECTS=$(\
  gcloud projects list \
  --format="value(projectId)")

for PROJECT in ${PROJECTS}
do
  echo "Project: ${PROJECT}"
  gcloud iam roles list \
  --project=${PROJECT} \
  --format="value(name)"
done
```

Or perhaps:

```bash
gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT}
```

And:

```bash
PROJECTS=$(\
  gcloud projects list \
  --format="value(projectId)")

for PROJECT in ${PROJECTS}
do
  echo "Project: ${PROJECT}"
  gcloud projects get-iam-policy ${PROJECT}
done
```

The above can be further filtered|formatted using `--filter` and `--format` flags.